# While loop in Javascript as long as modulo is 0

Tags: javascript

I want to write a function that divides a number n-times as long as the modulo is 0. For instance:

```
solve (1000) returns 2
solve (1503) returns 3
```

My try

```js
function solve(n) {
  let counter;

  while (n % 500 === 0) {
    counter += n % 500
    n++
  }
  return counter
}

console.log( solve(1000) )
console.log( solve(1503) )
```

When invoked, the function returns 'NaN'. I guess because the while-loop is not applied for some reason. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Well, "counter", when you write "let counter" contains "undefined" rather than '0', so of course it doesn't return a number. Other than that, I don't understand your question.

Comment: Assuming you fix the bug your logic does not implement what you describe. The code will run an infinite number of loops (never return) for 1000 and return 0 for 1503. Remember 0%anything === 0. So the while loop will first do 1000%500 which is 0 then 500%500 which is 0 then 0%500 which is also 0 then -500%500 which returns -0 which is also 0 etc.

Comment: 'NaN' means not a number, because you are trying to add a number to undefined, that's why you get NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the NaN issue you need to initialise your counter to 0.

```
let Counter=0;
```

However to find how many times a number can be divided by 500 you just need to do the following

```
Math.floor(1000/500)
//returns 2
Math.floor(1503/500)
//returns 3
```